# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'slice' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2013

I keep getting this message. When I try it in a "classic" HTML page it works fine. But when I try it in a VS 2013 I have this problem.

Unhandled exception at line 64, column 9 in ms-appx://eabd59c7-f115-49ff-9716-94243f12fc3b/js/Action.js 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'slice' of undefined or null referenc

I am new at this. Can someone help me?! Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Sage_Cell_Server</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Sage_Cell_Server references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/Action.js"></script>


    <script>

        $(function () {
            // Make *any* div with class 'compute' a Sage cell
            sagecell.makeSagecell({
                inputLocation: 'div.compute',
                template: sagecell.templates.minimal,
                evalButtonText: 'Evaluate'
            });

    // Make the div with id 'mycell' a Sage cell
    sagecell.makeSagecell({
        inputLocation: '#mycell',
        template: sagecell.templates.minimal,
        evalButtonText: 'Activate'

    });
});
    </script>



</head>
<body>
    <h1>Embedded Sage Cells</h1>

    <h2>Factorial</h2>
    Click the “Activate” button below to calculate factorials.
    <div id="mycell">
        <script type="text/x-sage">
            @interact
            def _(a=(1, 10)):
            print factorial(a)
        </script>
    </div>

    <h2>Your own computations</h2>
    Type your own Sage computation below and click “Evaluate”.
    <div class="compute">
    <script type="text/x-sage">
        plot(sin(x), (x, 0, 2*pi))
    </script></div>
    <div class="compute">
        <script type="text/x-sage">
            @interact
            def f(n=(0,10)):
            print 2^n
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Action.js ---> here is the problem

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['sagecell._setAccount', 'UA-29124745-1']);
_gaq.push(['sagecell._setDomainName', 'sagemath.org']);
_gaq.push(['sagecell._trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

(function() {
"use strict";
var undefined;

// Make a global sagecell namespace for our functions
window.sagecell = window.sagecell || {};

if (!document.head) {
    document.head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
}

var $ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
if (jQuery === undefined) {
    window.$ = jQuery = $;
}
sagecell.jQuery = $;

sagecell.URLs = {};

(function () {
    /* Read the Sage Cell server's  root url from one of the following locations:
         1. the variable sagecell.root
         2. a tag of the form <link property="sagecell-root" href="...">
         3. the root of the URL of the executing script */
    var el;
    if (sagecell.root) {
        sagecell.URLs.root = sagecell.root;
    } else if ((el = $("link[property=sagecell-root]")).length > 0) {
        sagecell.URLs.root = el.last().attr("href");
    } else {
        /* get the first part of the last script element's src that loaded something called 'embedded_sagecell.js'
           also, strip off the static/ part of the url if the src looked like 'static/embedded_sagecell.js'
           modified from MathJax source
           We could use the jquery reverse plugin at  http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss@jquery.com/msg04272.html 
           and the jquery .each() to get this as well, but this approach avoids creating a reversed list, etc. */
        var scripts = (document.documentElement || document).getElementsByTagName("script");
        var namePattern = /^.*?(?=(?:static\/)?embedded_sagecell.js)/;
        for (var i = scripts.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var m = (scripts[i].src||"").match(namePattern);
            if (m) {
                var r = m[0];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (r === "" || r === "/") {
            r = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
        }
        sagecell.URLs.root = r;
    }
    if (sagecell.URLs.root.slice(-1) !== "/") {
        sagecell.URLs.root += "/";
    }
}());

...
```

Comment: or when i remove that line i get this message
Unhandled exception at line 64, column 9 in ms-appx://eabd59c7-f115-49ff-9716-94243f12fc3b/js/Action.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'slice' of undefined or null reference

and i think that the problem is in that script(debuger cant read it till the end)

Comment: this problem is solved :D but now i have this error Unhandled exception at line 64, column 9 in ms-appx://eabd59c7-f115-49ff-9716-94243f12fc3b/js/Action.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'slice' of undefined or null reference  (its in that embedded_sagecell script)

Comment: I would guess that the Action.js script is not loading on the page.  Run some tests to make sure that is loading.  The relative path could be incorrect, also try adding type="Text/Javascript" to your script tags.

Comment: that script <script src="https://sagecell.sagemath.org/static/embedded_sagecell.js"></script>  is not loadnig corectly it keep sending me this error, maybe I need to involve some library or something... the script is corect because it works in an web page (HTML document)